# SQL Primary key struggle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table for suppliers group and when I try to create it it throws an error.

Here's the code :

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS  
(
    PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(3),
    GROUP_ID NUMBER(4),    
    GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(255),   
    SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(4),    

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID),   
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_ID FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS (SUPPLIER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER (4),
    PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (255),
    PRODUCT_SIZE VARCHAR2 (10),
    PRODUCT_GROUP NUMBER (4),
    PRODUCT_PRICE NUMBER(4),
    NO_IN_STOCK NUMBER (4),
    REORDER_LEVEL NUMBER (4),

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_ID FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP) REFERENCES GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(GROUP_ID)
);
```

This is the error message I am getting :

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Here's what I am trying to add in group plus suppliers:

```
INSERT INTO GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS VALUES (1,705,'flavoured oil',5588);
INSERT INTO GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS VALUES (2,705,'flavoured oil',5509);
INSERT INTO GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS VALUES (3,800,'spice',5543);
INSERT INTO GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS VALUES (4,800,'spice',5579);
INSERT INTO GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS VALUES (5,800,'spice',5584);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `SUPPLIER_ID` declared as primary key in `SUPPLIERS` table? and the id's 5588, etc. added in it?

Comment: Yes It is declared as primary key

Comment: What's the idea behind using Number(4)? Seems like a code error waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `GROUP_ID` column is not unique, and foreign key constraints cannot be made to non-unique values (which single row does it relate to?), and given that your `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS` table also uses `SUPPLIER_ID`, then you have to have a composite foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS (
    PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(3), -- better not to have this column
    GROUP_ID NUMBER(4),
    GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(255), -- violates 2nd normal form!
    SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(4),

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_ID FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS (SUPPLIER_ID)
    -- A new constraint
    CONSTRAINT UQ_PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID_GROUP_ID UNIQUE (SUPPLIER_ID, GROUP_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER (4),
    PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2 (255),
    PRODUCT_SIZE VARCHAR2 (10),
    PRODUCT_GROUP NUMBER (4),
    PRODUCT_PRICE NUMBER(4),
    NO_IN_STOCK NUMBER (4),
    REORDER_LEVEL NUMBER (4),

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID),
    -- a changed constraint
    CONSTRAINT FK_GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_SUPPLIER_ID_GROUP_ID 
       FOREIGN KEY ( SUPPLIER_ID, PRODUCT_GROUP)
       REFERENCES GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(SUPPLIER_ID, GROUP_ID)
);
```

It's possible I could be off base in this recommendation, and the FK instead needs to point to the `GROUPS` table, which you need to create if it doesn't exist. It's also a possible solution to make your FK point to the `PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID` column, but I promise you that doing that will create serious problems for you down the road, when you discover that to query your products table by group you will always be forced to join to another table. I predict quite confidently that you will deeply regret it if you do that.

There are also some serious issues with the database design.

1. Seeing your updated example for what you want in the `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS` table, it is very bad for `GROUP_NAME` to be in that table, because this violates [second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form). You need a `GROUPS` table with the `GROUP_ID` and the `GROUP_NAME` columns there.
2. The `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS` table appears to be a many-to-many join table, and almost certainly doesn't need its own ID column. I promise that this is true 99% of the time, and that it's better for any other tables referring to this logical relation (a unique relationship between a `SUPPLIER_ID` and a `GROUP_ID`) to just use a composite key. You'll thank me down the road for this.
3. `NUMBER(4)` seems awfully low. Are you sure there will never, ever, ever be more than 9999 products? Even for suppliers this sounds too low. Save yourself a  major headache later and make these reasonably large enough to accommodate a real-world enterprise-level scenario.

Also, please forgive me if I'm being uncomplimentary, but your naming scheme needs some work. I know some older versions of Oracle require all upper case and can't handle lower case, so I guess ignore that part if that's what you're working with.

1. Don't use all upper case with underscores. At *least* use Pascal Case, or all lower case with underscores. Better would be `GroupID` or `GroupId` and so on.
2. Name columns the same in all tables. Don't call it `GROUP_ID` in one table and `PRODUCT_GROUP` in another. Not doing so is, frankly, ridiculous and will lead to confusion and hatred for you by future developers. The next developer to work with this database after you had better not know your address!
3. `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS` is unnecessarily wordy. Just use `SUPPLIERS_GROUPS`.
4. Don't put the table name before every conceivable column. Just don't. I suppose it's okay for column names that are common to many tables, such as `Description`, but don't do it for the others. (In fact, that's why in my own tables I stopped using `Descr` or `Description` entirely, and now just call the column the singular of the table name--although my tables are singular, too, e.g., the `ProductStatus` table would have name column `ProductStatus` instead of `ProductStatusDescription` or `Description` or some other monstrosity.)

Here's what I think a far more sensible naming scheme and database designe would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups (
   GroupID NUMBER(4),
   GroupName VARCHAR2(255), -- I would normally call this Group but that's reserved

   CONSTRAINT PK_Groups PRIMARY KEY (GroupID),
   CONSTRAINT UQ_Groups_GroupName UNIQUE (GroupName)
);

CREATE TABLE SupplierGroups (
    GroupID NUMBER(4),    
    SupplierID NUMBER(4),

    CONSTRAINT PK_SupplierGroups PRIMARY KEY (SUPPLIER_ID, GROUP_ID),   
    CONSTRAINT FK_SupplierID FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) REFERENCES Suppliers (SupplierID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_GroupID FOREIGN KEY (GroupID) REFERENCES Groups (GroupID)
);

CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID NUMBER (4),
    ProductDescription VARCHAR2 (255),
    Size VARCHAR2 (10),
    GroupID NUMBER (4),
    Price NUMBER(4),
    NoInStock NUMBER (4),
    ReorderLevel NUMBER (4),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Products PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Products_SupplierID_GroupID FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID, GroupID)
       REFERENCES SupplierGroups (SupplierID, GroupID)
);
```

Comment: If my answer was instrumental in helping you find your solution, please click the check mark at the top left of it to indicate you accept my answer as the solution.

Comment: "Don't use all upper case with underscores. At least use Pascal Case, or all lower case with underscores. Better would be GroupID or GroupId and so on" -- oracle object names are case insensitive, so they can be written as `group_id`, or `Group_ID`, or `GROUP_ID`, and these are all interpreted the same. When the database displays the column names it generally does so in upper case, so while you're free to use `GroupID` the system will display it as `GROUPID`. You can make object names case sensitive by double-quoting them, but this is almost universally discouraged.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I guess I'm used to a database system that does a better job with displaying upper and lower case (even in a case insensitive database). Boo on Oracle for displaying all upper case!

Comment: @ErikE Well, it's only the display when you do a describe. Personally I use lower case for SQL as it's easier to read and spot errors in. I don't know why people use upper case for SQL -- maybe they think it's faster.

Comment: @David I use PascalCase because the difference in height between the upper and lower case letters provides greater differentiation, and I believe this is supported in the typographic world with solid research that mixed case is easier to read than all upper or all lower.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says what you are missing. The foreign key to `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(GROUP_ID)` means you need to add a unique index on this column.

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS  
(
    PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(3),
    GROUP_ID NUMBER(4),    
    GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(255),   
    SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(4),    

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID),   
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_ID FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS (SUPPLIER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT AK_GROUP_ID UNIQUE(GROUP_ID)
);
```

Comment: Tried that But when I try to add value it throws an error 'code'ORA-00001: unique constraint (AK_GROUP_ID) violated 'code'

Comment: No. You cannot insert a row that has the same GROUP_ID as another. You cannot accomplish both a foreign key to GROUP_ID and allow duplicate values into the column.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. I am trying to add duplicate values in GROUP_ID

Comment: Then you cannot use GROUP_ID as the principal key in this foreign key relationship. It violates the way foreign keys work.

Comment: All I want to do is add duplicate values for GROUP_ID as one group has different suppliers.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint `FK_GROUP_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_ID` on the `PRODUCTS` table should not reference `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(GROUP_ID)`. It should reference `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID)` instead.

```
...
CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_ID FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP) REFERENCES GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS(PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID)
...
```

If you really intend that to be a FK to just the `GROUP_ID`, then there should be a `GROUP` table, where `GROUP_ID` is the primary key, that you should reference.

```
...
CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_ID FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP) REFERENCES GROUP(GROUP_ID)
...
```

Comment: This is only one way to solve it—there are other ways (see my answer). In fact, I would suggest this way is sub-optimal, because while it works, it hides some serious problems that exist with the design.

Answer (score -1):

If lack of uniqueness is the real reason for the error, then you must use a compound PK to ensure uniqueness:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS  
(
    PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(3),
    GROUP_ID NUMBER(4),    
    GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(255),   
    SUPPLIER_ID NUMBER(4),    

    CONSTRAINT GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID,GROUP_ID,GROUP_NAME,SUPPLIER_ID),   
    CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER_ID FOREIGN KEY (SUPPLIER_ID) REFERENCES SUPPLIERS (SUPPLIER_ID)
);
```

This will allow you to add duplicate GROUP_ID values and yet satisfy the required matching uniqueness.

Comment: It is not a good idea to make every column in the table part of the primary key. Do you realize that this makes all these columns get duplicated in every row of any indexes on the table?

Comment: @ErikE, why do you any more indexes if the PK provides complete coverage?

Comment: Never going to query the `GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS_PK` table by `GROUP_ID` or `SUPPLIER_ID`, eh? I think you're not understanding what the purpose of an index is. Without an index with `GROUP_ID` first, a query like `SELECT * FROM GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS WHERE GROUP_ID = 1234` will result in a *scan*, not a *seek*. **That is bad**.

Comment: @ErikE, perhaps you're hobbled by myths of scans vs. seeks without recognizing why unique projections are needed.

Comment: I have been doing databases for 15 years and I'd wager you $1000 on this without hesitation, as long as the table was large enough for the query engine to not decide that reading all the pages was faster than seeking (as is common in small tables). But perhaps I am hobbled. Please explain how my example query in my comment will perform well in a large table without an index on `GROUP_ID`?

Comment: I've been in db longer than you and I don't wager. Sorry.

Comment: okay, no wager. :) I was just saying that for emphasis. Could you answer the question? In a large table, say, >100 MB, how will the engine satisfy `SELECT * FROM GROUPS_PLUS_SUPPLIERS WHERE GROUP_ID = 1234` with your proposed PK and no indexes? And what will its performance be compared to something more sensible like my design where the PK is `(SUPPLIER_ID, GROUP_ID)` and there is an index on `(GROUP_ID, SUPPLIER_ID)`? Even with the horribly wrong `GROUP_NAME` column present, and the (debatably) wrong `PRODUCT_GROUP_SUPPLIER_ID` column present?

Comment: Where in the OP's question does it say 100MB size? Who's complaining about performance? And who says your design is complete or even sensible to the problem at hand? If anything, your redesign is incomplete, insufficient to solve all perceived problems you raise, and ultimately not completely normalized, optimized, or tested for this OP's question.

Comment: Those are fair points. However, adding those columns to the PK means the table is set up to usher future developers into "the pit of failure" because they don't realize (when they do create an index some day because the table has grown) that it has other columns in the PK that, in the context of having other indexes on the table, are ridiculous. Wouldn't it be better to index-organize the table from the start and just make the PK cover only what the PK should contain in the case an index is needed?